# Spring Boot to Zipkin Error creating bean with name 'zipkinReporter'

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, zipkin

Please, anyone can help i'am use Spring Boot and Zipkin, here my configuration:

main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends Description {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication.run(Application, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

run test `mvn clean install`

got error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'zipkin2.reporter.Sender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("zipkinSender")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 162 more
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.576 s <<< FAILURE! - in id.idtrust.billing.BillingApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springRabbitTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/messaging/BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration$SleuthRabbitConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'springRabbitTracing' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/messaging/BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'messagingTracing' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/BraveAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tracing' parameter 5; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkinSpanHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/zipkin2/ZipkinBraveConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'zipkinSpanHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkinReporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/zipkin2/ZipkinAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reporter' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'zipkin2.reporter.Sender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("zipkinSender")}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springRabbitTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/messaging/BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration$SleuthRabbitConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'springRabbitTracing' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/messaging/BraveMessagingAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'messagingTracing' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tracing' defined in class path resource
```

have try add `@EnableConfigurationProperties({KafkaProperties.class, RabbitProperties.class})` on main class and the error is same, are there any settings missing ?

i think error on rabbit mq, i have try disable but the error same but without error rabbitTemplate `spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration`